# OpenVPN client opens a random UDP port?

Tags: openvpn, port, udp

We are noticing this on a number of our openvpn **clients**:

```
[root@box ~]# netstat -tulpn | grep openvpn
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53950               0.0.0.0:*                               1562/openvpn
[root@box ~]#
```

I am having a hard time finding any info via google regarding what is causing openvpn to open this random UDP port.

This port is random as it differs on each box, and when one restarts openvpn.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you paste a client config into your question?

Answer (score 2):

We have found the issue causing this.

We had **nobind** in our openvpn client conf.

After removing nobind, and adding the following:

```
bind
local {OUR LAN IP}
```

The 0.0.0.0:PORT listen has changed to whatever IP we provide in "local".

Comment: Please accept your own answer as suggested in the SO FAQ.

Comment: Would love to... Even tried right after I entered the answer... But unfortunately I am not "allowed": "You can accept your own answer tomorrow".